# Unable to access Json using http.get . status is coming out is -1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http, get

I am new to AngularJS. In my code, I am trying to access a json data using `$http.get`, but it is going to error and status is returning as -1 .

What is going wrong?

```
RecordApp.factory('recordaccess', ['$http', function($http) {
    $http.get('http://someurlforjson')
        .success(function(data) {
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("Error occurred. Status: " + status);
        });
}]);
```

Comment: cross origin problem may be

Comment: he's returning data in success callback.. may be that is the problem

Comment: it is very straight forward to make a get request using angular. What happens when you copy the url you are making the `get` request to in the browser. Does the url you are calling work? Also, what is a -1 error, I have never heard of that

Comment: Thank you Paul.. Yes when I paste the url in browser it works.. Even I am not sure of this status -1.

Comment: What does `data` in your `error()` function log as?

Comment: data is returning "undefined" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $http legacy promise methods `success` and `error` have been deprecated. Use the standard `then` method instead:

```
RecordApp.factory('recordaccess', ['$http', function($http) {
    return $http.get('http://someurlforjson')
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
            return response.data;
        },
        function errorCallback(response) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
            alert("Error occurred. Status: " + reponse.status + " - " + response.statusText);
        });
}]);
```

You can find more information in the [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

If this doesn't help, there must be something wrong with the path to your JSON (either the path is not correct or you're not allowed to access it, e.g. CORS).

Comment: Thank you Mastertinner for guiding me on this . I tried your code but that also ended up with same status code of -1 . I am suspecting the same cross domain issue, but not sure why I am getting -1 in status . Also, response.statusText is coming blank . 

Can someone help me handling issue of Cross domain issue .

Comment: Where will this `return` to? Without the `$http` being returned to variable or function you have no access to return of the callback either

Comment: @varunkumar, what if you add a `return` in front of the statement as I just did in my answer?

Comment: I got into one medical emergency .Now I am back to work .Can someone please check my below code and let me know whet wrong I am doing here .I am using a local json just to try new method of then :


    RecordApp.factory('recordaccess', ['$http', function($http) {
    return $http.get('record1.json')
    then(function successCallback(response) {
    return response.data;
    },
    function errorCallback(response) {alert("Error occurred. Status: " +          response.status + " - " +     response.statusText);
    });
    }]);

Comment: @varunkumar, you need to have a "." before the "then":
RecordApp.factory('recordaccess', ['$http', function($http) { return $http.get('record1.json').then(function successCallback(response) { return response.data; }, function errorCallback(response) {alert("Error occurred. Status: " + response.status + " - " + response.statusText); }); }]);

Comment: Somehow "." did not went through but I am using "." before then . Still it is not working . As the error says , the issue is from my controller .
Error says "TypeError: recordaccess.success is not a function" .

Comment: RecordApp.factory('recordaccess', ['$http', function($http) {return      $http.get('record.json')
    .then(function successCallback(response) {  
    return response.data; },
    function errorCallback(response) {
    alert("Error occurred. Status: " + response.status + " - " +      response.statusText);
    });
    }]);

Comment: RecordApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'recordaccess', function($scope, recordaccess) {
    recordaccess.success(function(data) {
        $scope.record1 = data;
   });
}]);

Comment: I have marked this as answered and I will create another thread because now the issue is diff. Thank you guys for your active support .